# Slimmest cURL calling

Tags: php, curl

What is the absolute *slimmest* way to only get the HTML of a URL? Basically for CURL to download least amount of data to save up on memory and speed.

I currently use:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/path/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I believe there are some parameters/options you can add to make it considerably slimmer.

Comment: Is web page scraping an option?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need any of the features of `curl`, use `file_get_contents`.

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://example.com/path/")
```

Comment: @ChristineCooper HTTP doesn't interpret the file contents. You can distinguish the different parts of the HTML until you download it and parse it.